# Database connectivity error in JSP

Tags: jsp, database-connection, registration

i have created a registration page in jsp. My Database is in MS Access. Apache Tomcat server is running.
When I click on submit button it is showing error in the following line:

```
Connection db=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:demo");
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you create DSN with name "demo"?

Comment: we need a stack trace

Comment: @Saurabh provide stacktrace or atleast the error you get